# Is there a function in SQL that automatically generates more rows by month?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a large database that's got all our transactions and shipping costs from them, here's a simplified version:

Source Table

| Date | ROUTE | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/20/21 | USA to UK | $40 |
| 01/01/21 | USA to UK | $40 |
| 01/10/21 | USA to UK | $40 |
| 12/20/20 | USA to UK | $30 |
| 11/20/20 | USA to UK | $20 |
| 11/20/20 | USA to UK | $20 |

And I want to see the average cost by month before so it would look like:

| Route | Nov 2020 | Dec 2020 | Jan 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA to UK | $20 | $30 | $40 |

How do I write a code that I can repeat for when say April comes around and I have to refresh this table and I don't need to create new columns for Feb, March, etc.?

Comment: The term you should google for is `pivot`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way of doing it by using PIVOT in Snowflake: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html

Let's say "monthname" is a column you extracted out of your "Date"-column, probably this helps:

```
select * from yourTable
pivot(sum(cost) for monthname in ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April'))
order by route;
```

The values of your monthname-column should match the one in the brackets.

As this is a more static solution, you still have to adjust the code every month. Here probably writing a stored procedure is helping: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html